# How to call AngularJS function after partial postback in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

How to call AngularJS function after partial postback (from ascx page) in ASP.Net inside an `UpdatePanel`. Initially I call angular function on `ng-init`. But after the partial postback, the function is not called. How could I call the function?

Function name is `BindLeadGridHeader`. Here is my Angular JS code:

```
.controller('CtrlSalesNav', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $location, $timeout) {
           //function for Bind Module Name Drop Down Created By :Prashant Kumar OnDate:21.04.2017  
           var UserId = sessionStorage.CurrentUserId;
           var CurrentModuleName = 'Lead';
           $scope.AllHeader = '';
           //code for bind all header to table 
           $scope.BindLeadGridHeader = function () {
               $http.get(WebApiUrl + "api/GetAllLeadHeader?UserId=" + UserId + "&ModuleName=" + CurrentModuleName).then(function (response) {
                   alert('Header bind call');
                   $scope.AllHeader = response.data.Table;
```

Calling code on ascx page inside UpdatePanel:

```
  <div class="lead_noTopMenu" id="divLeadGrid" ng-controller="CtrlSalesNav" ng-cloak>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 90px;" data-ng-init="BindLeadGridHeader();">
                <!-- Search FORM-->
                <div class="row row1" id="search" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="tabbable tabbable-custom">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
```

Comment: If you're just getting started with this, I'd highly recommend you visit: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md for guidance on best practices. Your use of $scope, lack of a data service and ng-init are all code smells. These are all things to be avoided and all things that will make migrating to current version of angular much more difficult for you down the road. All that being said, exactly where do you want to call this function from?

Comment: I want to call this function from .ascx page after partial post back .I have tired angular.element(document.getelementById('divLeadGrid)). scope().BindLeadGridHeader();                                                       but this one console an error scope(...). BindLeadGridHeader is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be using an angular directive or component. There's a 3rd callback on promises that's rarely used, called notify, that might work for you. It's called while the promise is waiting to be resolved.